# Predict a value from continuous data with scikit

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm new to scikit and need to learn how to predict a value based on multiple continuous data columns. Here I have several data columns which has continuous data as follows. (column names are only for example reference)

```
ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColE
8.0     307.0   130.0   3504.0  12.0
15.0    350.0   165.0   3693.0  11.5
18.0    318.0   150.0   3436.0  11.0
16.0    304.0   150.0   3433.0  12.0
17.0    302.0   140.0   3449.0  10.5
15.0    429.0   198.0   4341.0  10.0
14.0    454.0   220.0   4354.0  9.0
14.0    440.0   215.0   4312.0  8.5
....
....
```

What I need to do is predict a value in ColA based on a model created by feeding above data. I see only examples of classifying the predicted value. How to obtain the actual value if any/all of ColB, ColC, ColD, ColE value is given?

Can anyone help me on this how to do it with scikit?

Comment: you can use a lot of models like linear regression [see here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) After fitting the model using the data, you will use predict() method to get the predictions. to you want me to provide an example? If yes can you upload the data ?

Comment: Thanks Sera. It would be helpful to me if you can put some code snippets here. I know how to load the data to a tabular structure. I'm confused with parameters passed to fit method and the correct way for coding it. Say I have all the data loaded into a structure called sample_data. Should pass a submodel of ColB, ColC, ColD, ColE as X and ColA as y? How to pass value for predict?

Comment: Yes this is the right approach. I will post some code in some minutes. X and y should be arrays. Also pandas module is really helpful for loading / splitting the data. I will create a simple example using the data that you posted.

Comment: Thanks again. Code will be helpful for me as I'm learning from the beginning. If you need the full url for the data file here is the link. http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/ This original file contain some missing values. So it needs additional cleanup with missing values. Therefore just way of doing the prediction will be sufficient for me.

Comment: I will modify the code for the missing data. one moment I just show your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I converted the data to a csv file so that I can use pandas.
The csv is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sxiksjzhgfzen1j/data.csv?dl=0)

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',header = None)

#Fill the missing data with 0 and the '?' that you have with 0
df = df.fillna(0)
df= df.replace('?', 0)

X = df.iloc[:,1:7]

#I assume than the y is the first column of the dataset as you said
y = df.iloc[:,0]

#I split the data X, y into training and testing data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

#Convert pandas dataframes into numpy arrays (it is needed for the fitting)
X_train = X_train.values
X_test = X_test.values
y_train = y_train.values
y_test = y_test.values

#Create and fit the model
model = LinearRegression()

#Fit the model using the training data
model.fit(X_train,y_train)

#Predict unseen data
y_predicted =model.predict(X_test)
scores = model.score(X_test, y_test)

print(y_predicted)
print(scores)
```

The result of the first printing is the **predicted values** **for the unseen** (X_test) **features**. The predicted values correspond to the 1st column of the dataset.

The result of the second printing returns the coefficient of determination R^2 of the prediction.

More [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.score)

**P.S:** The problem that you want to address is too general.

First, you could scale the features (X array) using for example the `StandardScaler` method from sklearn. This is in general good, it can improve the performance but it is on you. More details [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html)

Next, instead of using `train_test_split`, you could other methods to split the data.

Finally, instead of LinearRegression you could use other methods.

Hope this helps

Comment: I did click upvote. Hope the system will update later.